# which config/version gradle in android studio for an old cordova project ? 4.6? 3.2.1?

Tags: android, gradle, configuration, build.gradle

I'm completly lost, I have to update an application my company make. It is a cordova build. 
I try to launch it in Android studio to test and ... here we are in hell.

Mistake after mistake, bug after bug . I don't know what to do.

First of all, this "gradle" :

1. In `file/project structure` [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrdVW.png) which configuration set
   ? I put 4.6 and 2.2.3
2. In `Gradle Scripts/gradle-wrapper.properties` I put the 4.6 but
   i'm not sure at all... `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip`
3. In `Gradle Scripts/build.gradle` I add a line `google()` in

buildscript and allproject like :
     `buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }`

and change the version of gradle to 4.6

```
 `dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6'
}`
```

4. I see also I have to change (in the same file) :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}
and use `implementation project(':library')` instead

5. I see also I have to modify, as in scr gradle file , in `CordavaLib/build.gradle` as point 3.

And then I have still many error, I uninstall many time android studio, I still have 'sync finish event has not been received' whit a huge log

```
Gradle sync failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslSettableExpression.<init>(GradleDslSettableExpression.java:36)
            .........
```

And I don't understand why,

If someone could help me with this configuration it will be great, i'm completely desperate... :(
I just want to build my apk and my keystore ...

When I make 'Build/Clear' I get Build completed **successfully** , but  when I change the **build variant** from **debug** to **release** i get :

```
  Unable to select build variant 'realease': cannot find module with gradlepath ':CordovaLib'
```